# I want to modify root files while also being able to create non-root files in a single text editor session. 

Tags: filesystems, permissions, editors

Catch 22: If I open my text editor **without** using `sudo`, I don't have permission to save any changes.  If I open it **with** root privileges, any files I create are owned by root.  I want to be able to create files that are owned by me (non-root user), and also edit files that require root access in the same session.  Possible?  Is this a Linux thing or a text editor setting?

I'm using Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `sudoedit` to edit your root-owned text files, then your editor will be running as you. Sudoedit works by making a temporary copy of the root-owned file(s), owned by you, and invoking your editor (chosen via `$SUDO_EDITOR`, `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, or the sudoers config file) on it. When you quit the editor, it copies the temporary file(s) back if they're modified. Full details are in the man page.